# Will the GTS perform circular trades?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

Say I've deposited a Pokemon, and I am asking for another one. Meanwhile, two other Trainers have deposited their Pokemon, and it works out that if we trade in a circular fashion, we'd all get what we want.

For example,

- Robotnik puts up *Snubbull*, asks for *Skarmory*.
- Bill puts up *Skarmory*, asks for *Oddish*.
- Steve puts up *Oddish*, asks for *Snubbull*.

Will the GTS perform a circular trade?

Comment: I'm not saying this definitely doesn't happen, but I don't even think the GTS does this with two open offers that complement each other, so I wonder what might have made you think that it would do it with 3 or more.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - I'm fairly certain it does it with two offers, I've deposited a Pokemon and before I could even leave the GTS it had been traded (I clicked on 'Check status' accidentally when leaving). Can you imagine the buildup if it didn't?

Comment: @murgatroid99 - And what made me think this might happen, is I got a Japanese Level 1 Charmander (female) from a Guy in Iowa, and the OT was a girl from Japan. I'm not saying this guy was dumb, perhaps he really *really* needed my male Eevee.

Comment: I guess it could do pairs. But do you expect it do 3? or 4? or arbitrary length cycles? I would be very surprised if it did. And honestly, i'm not really sure why it matters. On the GTS, you put up a Pokemon and you might trade it for another. Does it matter whose Pokemon you got and which one the other guy got? Does this affect what you do in any way?

Comment: I don't think it does pairs - if it did I'm fairly certain there would be far fewer open "Haunter for Haunter" type trades open, and there where several when I went looking. If your pokemon was traded quickly, it's probably because there are a LOT of people hammering the GTS in these opening weeks looking for the pokemon they want. Especially as the current generation is temporarily cut off from previous ones.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - It may not affect what I do, but it would solve my confusion as to why someone would enter into such a terrible trade (from their end at least, I'm pretty stoked)

Comment: @TrentHawkins - Or it may be that the script only runs once an hour, or every 10 minutes or something. I've seen the "Haunter for Haunter" ones disappear in big batches, especially when browsing Vivillon or Scatterbug

Comment: What's the goal here? I don't quite get what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BenBrocka  - The goal is clarity, and a better understanding of how the system works - as I said I received a trade that doesn't make sense, and I'm trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there's such a thing such as a 'circular trade'.

In your given example:

- Robotnik puts up Snubbull, asks for Skarmory.
- Bill puts up Skarmory, asks for Oddish.
- Steve puts up Oddish, asks for Snubbull.

Nothing will happen. The GTS works in such a way that Bill has to find the Skarmory he's looking for and has to give an Oddish in exchange. GTS doesn't work like... Put your Pokemon and it will find a compatible trade pair, if that's how you're thinking it works. I've found several Ditto for Ditto trades a while ago and if it was automatic, there would be no such things.

Something to explain your trade occurrence:

There's a 'hidden' mechanic coined the Masuda Method which is used when breeding two Pokemon of different genders which heightens the odds of getting a shiny offspring. If that person bred a lot of Charmander at level 1, it wouldn't be any issue to get a non-Japanese Eevee, just to put more odds on his side and get shiny Eevees. Plus the one he gave you would be in his favour if he wanted to get a shiny Charmander anyway, since you mention it is Japanese.